# Simplify $((p\wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge r) \vee (q \wedge r))$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$((p\wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge r) \vee (q \wedge r))$

$\iff$ $(p\wedge q) \vee r\wedge(\neg p\vee q)$  (Distributive Law)

Not really sure where to go from here, need some hints please.

Comment: @semsem The right answer was provided already by following David's hint. I won't sait it in respect to the questioner. But it's not what you pointed out.

Comment: you are right I read the last $q$ as $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps that $(q \wedge r) \implies ((p\wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge r)).$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$[(p \wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge r) \vee (q \wedge r)]$$

$$\equiv [(p \wedge q) \vee (q \wedge r) \vee (\neg p \wedge r)] $$ its happens because of the commutativity of $\vee$

Then apply the Distributive Law

$$\equiv [q  \wedge(p \vee r) \vee (\neg p \wedge r) ]$$

and from here should be easy to simplify it.